# Swift and AVFoundation: Playing audio while animating a label

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiviewanimation

I have an app that I'm adding sounds to. It has a keypad and when the user taps a button, the number animates to show the user that their press went through.

However, since both are happening on the main thread, adding the following code below, the `play()` function causes a slight delay in the animation. If the user waits ~2 seconds and taps a keypad number again, they see the delay again. So as long as they're hitting keypad numbers under 2s, they don't see another lag.

I tried wrapping the code below in a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` block with no luck.

```
if let sound = CashSound(rawValue: "buttonPressMelody\(count)"),
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound.rawValue, withExtension: sound.fileType) {
    self.audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()

    self.audioPlayer?.play()
}
```

How can I play this audio and have the animation run without them interfering and with the audio coinciding with the press?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried playing the sound on a background thread instead of on the main queue? I believe that AVFoundation is able to be used on background threads.

Comment: I wrapped the above block in `DispatchQueue.performBackgroundAsync {` as well, the first play is delayed and off-animation. Doesn't block the animation (which is good!) but that first sound isn't firing on time

Comment: If you do it multiple times, does it delay every one of those times, or only the first time you do it?

Comment: The first one is delayed, and then if you wait ~2 seconds, the next play is delayed. If you hit them back to back to back, only the first play is delayed. even with the background threading

Comment: I haven't experienced this with AVFoundation, but when I did audio stuff back in the day with QTKit, I often tended to get a delay the first time I played a sound, as the system loaded the needed subsystems lazily. I worked around it by having it play a zero-length audio file at startup to warm everything up. May be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I think the zero-length file will help. I know in haptics you can use `prepare` to keep the haptics system warm for ~30 seconds. AVFoundation seems to behave a bit differently

Comment: Other thing that might help is to hang onto that `AVAudioPlayer` instance and just keep playing it again instead of recreating it every time.

Comment: I use different sounds for each different button in the keypad, or I would

Comment: Maybe stash a separate instance for each sound that can play?

Comment: I don't really want 9 instances of AVAudioPlayers...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a rather similar problem in my SwiftUI app, and in my case the solution was in proper resource loading / AVAudioPlayer initialization and preparing.

I use the following function to load audio from disk (inspired by ImageStore class from Apple's Landmarks SwiftUI Tutorial)

```swift
final class AudioStore {
    typealias Resources = [String:AVAudioPlayer]
    fileprivate var audios: Resources = [:]

    static var shared = AudioStore()


    func audio(with name: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        let index = guaranteeAudio(for: name)

        return audios.values[index]
    }

    static func loadAudio(with name: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3") else { fatalError("Couldn't find audio \(name).mp3 in main bundle.") }
        do { return try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) }
        catch { fatalError("Couldn't load audio \(name).mp3 from main bundle.") }
    }
    fileprivate func guaranteeAudio(for name: String) -> Resources.Index {
        if let index = audios.index(forKey: name) { return index }

        audios[name] = AudioStore.loadAudio(with: name)
        return audios.index(forKey: name)!
    }
}
```

---

1. In the view's init I initialize the player's instance by calling audio(with:) with proper resource name.
2. In onAppear() I call prepareToPlay() on view's already initialized player with proper optional unwrapping, and finally
3. I play audio when the gesture fires.

Also, in my case I needed to delay the actual playback by some 0.3 seconds, and for that I despatched it to the global queue. I should stress that the animation with the audio playback was smooth even without dispatching it to the background queue, so I concluded the key was in proper initialization and preparation. To delay the playback, however, you can only utilize the background thread, otherwise you will get the lag.

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
   ///your audio.play() analog here
}
```

Hope that will help some soul out there.